# как присвоить переменной значение из таблицы msyql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

у меня есть подключенная таблица из Mysql в проект java, мне нужно вывыести сумму значений в таблице, простым запросом в mysql я бы выполнил 
"select sum(score) from temp"
, но мне нужно присвоить его в переменную

```
    System.out.println(statement.execute("select sum(score) from " + user));
```

не работает так, как нужно :/

Comment: В переменной user значение верное?

Comment: да, это тот же temp,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statement.execute` возвращает boolean. Данные извлечены - true,нет - false
Чтобы распечатать сами данные

```
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select sum(score) as total from " + user);
     if(result.next()){
         String sum = result.getString("total");
         System.out.println(sum);
     }
```